# Button highlight behavior changed on Froyo?

Tags: android, user-interface, button

On Android 2.1, just as on most graphical computer OSes, pressing the mouse while in a button, then dragging away, then dragging back, then releasing (while within the button rectangle) would result in a button press.  It would also highlight while the mouse pointer was within (or actually near) the button, going off as the pointer left the zone, then back on when the pointer returned.

This behavior allows the user to cancel, mid-press, by dragging away from the button until its highlight is off and releasing; it also allows the user to change her mind about cancelling, so long as the mouse is still down, and go back into the button to "rescue" the click.

In 2.2, it appears that Android no longer allows a return to the button.  Dragging away cancels the highlight, but returning with the mouse still held down does not re-highlight the button, nor does an away-and-return click generate a click event.

So, my questions: Is this change real (has anyone else seen it)?  and: Is it intentional?  What is the rationale for this change, if it is intentional?

Comment: Never noticed. But I can confirm that your observation seems to be true. I'm using a custom 2.2 ROM, and I experience the same button behaviour as you are describing.

Comment: I can't really test on 2.1 or prior, but it does what you say on 2.2. To me, it makes sense this way. Imagine you have a button within a ListView. If you press the button, then move your finger to scroll the view, you wouldn't want the button to be pressed when you stopped scrolling. Similarly, if you had, say, a drag-and-drop action. If you move your finger while pressing the button, and drag the button elsewhere, you wouldn't necessarily want the button to press upon release.

Comment: Tested also in Android 4.0.4 (same behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Since I tested in an Android 4.0.4, I can guess this was intentional.

My guess is that they made the change to prevent some problems with people who are not used to touchable screens. It can also be to improve usability for people with disabilities. However, I'm not Google nor know the real reason of the change. Those were just my guesses.